# Sabre Car Rental API - One-way rental availability by City / Zip / Poi

Tags: sabre

I'm using the Ground Transportation SOAP API to fetch car rental availability by city/zip/poi using VehLocationFinderLLSRQ. It returns a list of locations and available vehicles, along with the total price. This works fine for regular rentals. However, I can't figure out a way to search for a one-way rental (by specifying a return location).

I'm aware of VehLocationListLLSRQ, which lets you specify a Pickup and Return location, but it requires a location code. I don't have a location code, but only a city/zip or poi.

For example, I'm interested in one-way rentals from "Copley Square, Boston(MA) to South Beach, Miami(FL)". What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Request Design Documentation](http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/VehLocationFinderLLSRQ_v2.2.0_Design.xml), you can specify whether a location is or not a drop-off location. Also, it states that the `<LocationDetails>` element has a repeat factor of 0 or 2.

So based on that information and the [example request](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/ground_transportation/search/Car_Locations), I would consider trying something like this:

```xml
<VehLocationFinderRQ Version="2.2.0">
    <VehAvailRQCore>
        <LocationDetails DropOff="false">
            <Address>
                <CityName>SOUTHLAKE</CityName>
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX" />
                <StreetNmbr>3150 SABRE DRIVE</StreetNmbr>
            </Address>
        </LocationDetails>
        <LocationDetails DropOff="true">
            <Address>
                <CityName>DALLAS</CityName>
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX" />
                <StreetNmbr>MAIN ST</StreetNmbr>
            </Address>
        </LocationDetails>
        <VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="12-22T09:00" ReturnDateTime="12-29T11:00" />
    </VehAvailRQCore>
</VehLocationFinderRQ>
```